# Can custom dbEdit receive notification of dataset AfterPost and AfterDelete events?

Tags: delphi

Hi I am trying to build a custom dbEdit which amongst other tasks will calculate its datafield's sum. Is there any way that this component can receive notification of its underlying datasets's AfterPost and AfterDelete events? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "calculate its datafield's sum"?  The implementation of a TDBEdit-descendant is not the right place to be calculating a field's aggregate ...  Which Delphi version btw?

Comment: I use delphi 7.  I thought that I would create and free a TQuery inside the component to calculate Sum etc  on component exit. I then realised that although this worked it did not take into account the underlying dataset deleting a record which has led me to TDataSetNotifyEvent sinceI posted the original question.

Comment: Sounds overdue for a re-think to me for the reason I said.  Creating a TQuery for each calculation would be horribly slow.  And if a user calls the dataset's DisableControls/EnableControls during an operation, you will not see possibly-relevant events.  You would do far better, imo, if you simply add dsInternalCalc calculated fields to calculate whatever you need.  What RDMS are you using btw?

Comment: I usw Absolute Database. Which is fine for my simple purposes.. Thank you for your doubts and the helpful suggestion which I will follow. Being fairly new at this can I vote you or click the up arrow?

Comment: Well, there is a mechanism here for upvoting answers, but I don't honestly think I could post an answer to your q atm because it does not contain nearly enough details about what your requirements are and what you are trying to achieve.  For example: what to do if user A's actions affect records of interest to user B.  The fancier you try to make the db's behaviour, the more like you are to end up with a system which is impracticable to implement and/or badly impacts multi-user responsiveness.

Comment: Sorry but that is what I meant. You've shown me all the pifalls of my idea so I am forgetting about it and will just use a TQuery